# Fastapi behaving differently when parameter is hadcoded

Tags: python, oauth, fastapi

I am new to Fastapi,
I'm trying to implement a new endpoint as such:

```py
@router.get("/{id_prevision}/x_operations",
            dependencies=[Depends(app.users.current_user(active=True))],
            response_model=List[PrevOpeSchema])
def list_x_operations(id_prevision: str, request: Request, response: Response,
                      db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    x_ope = (
        db.query(PrevOpe)
        .filter(
            PrevOpe.id_prevision == id_prevision
            and PrevOpe.flag_x is True
        )
        .join(Operation, Operation.id_operation == PrevOpe.id_operation)
    )

    results, headers = get_paginated_sql_results(request, x_ope, PrevOpe)
    response.init_headers(headers)
    return results
```

This implementation works fine (as long as I comment the dependency line) on the fastapi browser interface.

However, when I try this implementation, where I remove the `id_prevision` and harcode it. It doesn't work.

```py
@router.get("/x_operations/",
            # dependencies=[Depends(app.users.current_user(active=True))],
            response_model=List[PrevOpeSchema])
def list_x_operations(request: Request, response: Response,
                      db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    x_ope = (
        db.query(PrevOpe)
        .filter(
            PrevOpe.id_prevision == "1"
            and PrevOpe.flag_x is True
        )
        .join(Operation, Operation.id_operation == PrevOpe.id_operation)
    )

    results, headers = get_paginated_sql_results(request, x_ope, PrevOpe)
    response.init_headers(headers)
    return results
```

I get a `401 unauthorized` response

[image: FastAPI response]

I tried to debug the problem but the short error of FASTapi doesn't help

Comment: Do you have any dependency entries for the router itself (i.e. you can add dependencies on a router level instead of on a view)?

Comment: No I guess the problem was that (and I don't know if this is native to fastapi) but the routes that have parameters in them need to come last, meaning that routes like this `@router.get("/x_operations/"...)` should never come after a route like this `@router.get("/{id_prevision}/operation_details"...)`

Comment: Routes are always being checked in the order they were defined, so if you have any route defined above this one, which also catches the request you're trying to execute, it will be called instead of this route.